# My HTC Hero Upgrade to Android 2.1 has slowed it down!

Tags: performance, updates, calls

I went ahead and let my phone update itself and since then it's been realllly SLOW. Phone calls take 5-45 seconds to connect, which is beyond aggravating. Apps don't run as fast as they use to. And I am constantly reconnecting the Mobile network because it keeps losing it. Anyone have similar and get around it??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [brief post](http://tomaszdzido.com/blog/android-running-slow-htc-hero/) about speeding up a HTC Hero.

Are you with Sprint by any chance?

[This thread](http://androidforums.com/sprint-hero-support-troubleshooting/95376-htc-hero-slow-after-upgrading-2-1-a.html) and [this thread](http://androidforums.com/sprint-htc-hero/104368-dialing-lag.html) have at least one suggestion:  Have a look in Menu > settings > About phone > System updates > HTC Software update. Apparently there is a .6 firmware patch. Unfortunately, most of the posts are not reassuring. Perhaps time to upgrade/change phones?

Comment: It is a sprint phone, and other posts I've read on that site suggest calling sprint, they may replace it. I guess into the call queue I go!  Thanks!